# Could someone check my reasoning on these two probability problems?

Tags: probability

Below are two questions (which I think I answered wrongly). My answer for the first one is B because they cannot occur together at the same time, and my answer for the second question is D using the formula E=Zc. Can someone check my reasoning?

---

> $1$. Two mutually exclusive events
>
> > A. have the same probability
> >
> > B. cannot occur together
> >
> > C. have the sum of their probabilities equal to one
> >
> > D. have no effect on the occurrence of each other

---

> $2$. When a $99\%$ confidence interval is calculated instead of a $95\%$ confidence interval with sample size unchanged, the margin of error will be
>
> > A. the same
> >
> > B. smaller
> >
> > C. undetermined
> >
> > D. larger

Comment: You need to show some solving effort, my friend.

Comment: Why don't you add your thoughts regarding what you think *might be the answers*, and why. If you need clarification about the definitions involved here, we'll be happy to help, but please add your thoughts, and specify exactly where you are "stuck".

Comment: I am just guessing I got these 2 question wrong. For the first one my answer is B which I know they cannot happen at the same time.

Comment: Yes! That's right. That's what it means to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: For the 2nd one my answer is D. Like I say I am just guessing that these are the question that I was answering wrong

Comment: You should edit that into your post. It is on the verge of being put "on hold." Follow [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/448141/edit).

Comment: @dotslash: It has now been shown.

Comment: @amWhy: The OP responded to you, but didn't know to tag you.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to question 2 is D. You answered correctly. The margin of error is defined as c*Standard Error. c for 99% confidence is higher than 95%, thus the margin of error is larger. Intuitively, the more confident you want to be about the interval, the larger interval you have to have, thus allowing more room for errors. Because you want to "catch" the true parameter in your interval with a greater probablity by having a larger interval.